DB2 table functions
I want to return a table in a function with using the given parameters.
The statement will be at the end very long, that's why I want to use a cursor.
How I can solve the below error and retrieve the table from cursor as return value.
{0:0} An unexpected token "FOR" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "
DECLARE C1 CURSOR".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.28.11
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "TT"."MY_FUNC" ()
    RETURNS TABLE(LIMITT INT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    READS SQL DATA
    NO EXTERNAL ACTION
    DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN ATOMIC
    
    DECLARE STMT CLOB(1K);
    DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR S1;
    
    SET STMT = 'SELECT 1 FROM FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 LIMIT '''|| LIMITT ||'''';
    PREPARE S1 FROM STMT;
    OPEN C1;
    CLOSE C1;
    
    RETURN 
    --table
    END


Even if I not use the LIMIT variable, I still get the same error and how can I return the result of the cursor.

You might want to review examples in the documentation.

At least two problems with your example code in the question.
First problem is that the LIMIT clause cannot have a variable, it can only have a constant integer. In other words you cannot have LIMIT '''|| some_variable ||''''  , but you can have LIMIT 100   or LIMIT 1000 or whatever fixed number.
You are allowed to use dynamic-SQL in a compiled routine to make the final-SQL-query at run time (i.e. each time you do a prepare you can specify a different constant-integer), and then prepare and execute that code. This might be wasteful.  Study the docs and sample programs to learn how to work with dynamic SQL, as that is outside the scope of this answer.
Second problem is that you cannot use a cursor in an SQL-inlined function, i.e. in a function that is BEGIN ATOMIC.   You can make the function compiled by just using BEGIN (instead of BEGIN ATOMIC).
Another problem is that your descrption of why you think you need a cursor makes no sense.  To return a table you need RETURN (SELECT... FROM someTable) and that SELECT can be long and complicated. You appear to be learning, so time spent studing samples might be your best option.
Consider studying both the documentation and the sample programs to learn more. The sample programs are in your DB2-LUW server "samples" directory tree, they are also on github, and they are also in the Db2-LUW-Knowledge centre.
See the limitations on inlined-SQL in the documentation here https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=support-inline-sql-pl

Thx for clarification.
Do you have an example with dynamic sql using table functions.
